# Yii2: make a connection viaTable

Tags: sql, mysql, yii2

I have 3 tables:

```
news
id | title | text

companies
id | name

news_companies
id | news_id | company_id
```

I want to create a relationship in the News model so that I can get the data of all related companies. For this I do like this:

```
public function getCompanies(): \yii\db\ActiveQuery
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Companies::class, ['id' => 'company_id'])
            ->viaTable('news_companies', ['news_id' => 'id']);
    }
```

But when I run the query, I don't get the result I want

```
$query = $model->getCompanies();
dd($query->createCommand()->rawSql);

SELECT * FROM `companies` WHERE 0=1
```

I can't figure out what's wrong

Comment: How you define the `$model`?

Comment: The issue you're encountering, where the SQL query generated by Yii2's getCompanies() method returns no results (WHERE 0=1), suggests that there may be a problem with the relationships between your tables or the naming conventions used.